# Dynamically Name Sheet from Cell and Later Call Name of Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

In the code below, I am building a table on the "Shipped" sheet by pulling data from the "Efficiency" sheet using the criteria "Ship". I want to name the "Shipped" sheet dynamically from a cell by using something like `Application.ActiveSheet.Name = .Range("A2")` and then use that to call the sheet using something like `Set wsShip = Worksheets.Range("A2")` and I also want to use a dynamic criteria for pulling data, so instead of using `Criteria1:="Ship"`I want to use `Criteria1:=.Range("A3")` Is there any/another way to do this?

```
Sub DataTable()
    Dim wsEff As Worksheet
    Dim wsShip As Worksheet    
    ''Application.ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A2")
    'Need ' Set wsShip = Worksheets(Range("A2"))?
    Set wsShip = Worksheets("Shipped")
    Set wsEff = Worksheets("Efficiency")
    With wsEff
        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:H" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Ship"
        Dim rngCopy As Range
        'All Columns A:H
        Set rngCopy = .Columns("A:H")
        'filtered rows, not including header row - assumes row 1 is headers
        Set rngCopy = Intersect(rngCopy, .Range("A1:H" & lRow), .Range("A1:H" & lRow).Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rngCopy.Copy
        End With
    wsShip.Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False        
        Worksheets("Efficiency").ShowAllData
    End Sub
```

Comment: You know how to declare variables and store things to them. Do it again.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to *rename* the sheet or just use the cell value to refer to the correct sheet.   If the latter then your second commented-out line should be OK, with the note that you should specify which sheet you want to take A2 from.

Comment: I want to do both. Use the cell reference to rename the sheet and be able to dynamically call up the sheet name. I do not want to hard program a sheet name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set wsShip = Worksheets("Shipped")
Set wsEff = Worksheets("Efficiency")

wsShip.Name = wsEff.Range("A2").Value 'for example

wsShip.Activate 'changing the name doesn't change the reference to 
                '  the sheet you have in 'wsShip'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just using a source independent of the sheet itself.